# Прикрепить к письму фото отправленное пользователем и сохранённое в state proxy

Tags: python, aiogram, smtplib

Вот код хендлера где я принимаю фото от пользователя и сохраняю

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=[*types.ContentTypes.TEXT, *types.ContentTypes.PHOTO], state=ProfileStatesGroup.check)
async def load_it_info(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    if message.photo:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['check'] = message.photo[0].file_id
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                               text=lang_dict['passport'][data['lang']],
                               reply_markup=get_start_and_back_kb())
        await ProfileStatesGroup.passport1.set()
    if message.text == "":
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                               text="Выберите язык", reply_markup=lang_kb())
        await ProfileStatesGroup.language.set()
```

Вот код хендлера отправки письма

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=[*types.ContentTypes.TEXT], state=ProfileStatesGroup.phone_number)
async def load_it_info(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext) -> None:
    if message.text == "":
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                                   text=lang_dict['ch_number'][data['lang']], reply_markup=get_start_and_back_kb())
        await ProfileStatesGroup.ch_number.set()
    else:
        async with state.proxy() as data:
            data['phone_number'] = message.text
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                               text=lang_dict['phone_number'][data['lang']],
                               reply_markup=get_start_kb())
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=message.from_user.id,
                               text=lang_dict['telegram'][data['lang']])

        msg = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
        fromaddr = "bukanov1234@mail.ru"
        mypass = "6bUc5jT7is5Yvz4pYHLf"
        toaddr = "bukanov1234@mail.ru"
        msg['From'] = fromaddr
        msg['To'] = toaddr
        msg['Subject'] = "Отправитель: Telegram bot"
        html = f"""
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                    <head>
                    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                    </head>
                    <body> 
                    <h1>Страна: {data['country']} </h1>     
                    <h1>Выбранный язык: {data['lang']} </h1> 
                    <h1>Страна где родился: {data['country_where_born']} </h1> 
                    <h1>Город где родился: {data['town_where_born']} </h1>      
                    <h1>Страна от которой подают заявку: {data['country_where_green']} </h1>  
                    <h1>Семейное положение: {data['fam_status']} </h1>  
                    <h1>Образование: {data['edu']} </h1>  
                    <h1>Адрес проживания: {data['address']} </h1>  
                    <h1>Email: {data['email']} </h1> 
                    <h1>Количество детей(если есть): {data['ch_number']} </h1>   
                    <h1>Номер телефона: {data['phone_number']} </h1>      
                    </body>
                    </html>
                    """
        text = bs(html, "html.parser").text
        msg.attach(MIMEText(text, 'plain'))
        msg.attach(MIMEText(html, 'html', 'utf-8'))

          

        #Здесь я пытаюсь прикрепить фото из хендлера

        image_data = data['check']
        image_mime = MIMEImage(image_data)
        msg.attach(image_mime)

        #Здесь я пытаюсь прикрепить фото из хендлера


        server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.mail.ru:465')
        ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
        server.login(msg['From'], mypass)
        text = msg.as_string()
        server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], text)
        server.quit()
        await state.finish()
```

При попытке прикрепить картинку выдает ошибку:

if h.startswith(b'\211PNG\r\n\032\n'):
TypeError: startswith first arg must be str or a tuple of str, not bytes

Comment: А зачем у вас путь в виде байтовой строки? Конечно, выдает ошибку. Поменяйте на сырую, должно заработать.

Comment: У вас `b''`, а надо `r''`.

Comment: Я вас немного не понял , можете указать где?

Comment: В той строке, в которой у вас ошибка. Почитайте трейсбек. Там указывается файл и номер строки, в которой ошибка.

Comment: Дело в том что мне нужно изменить не фаил библиотеки а именно строки кода где я прикрепляю картинку присланную пользователем

Comment: Ну так исправьте там, кто вам мешает.

Comment: Я тут спрашиваю как это сделать, если не знаете просто пройдите мимо, зачем бы я писал вопрос на форуме если бы знал это

Comment: Не понял вас. Зайдите в файл, на который указывает трейсбэк, установите курсор на строку с указанным номером и исправьте `b''` на `r''`. Вот и все.